# How to redirect to different JSP page with the JSON result from spring rest controller and display those values in that jsp page

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

```
function submitForm() {
   var id = $("#id").val();
   var name = $("#name").val();
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify({
        "id":id,
        "name":name,
      }),
    dataType: "json", 
    url : "rest/emp/create",
    success : function(data) {
            //alert("created Employee"+data.name+data.id);
    }
});
}
```

i want to redirect to another jsp page with json response from spring controller.
in the above java script function i am calling a spring controller to create an employee data. after successful creation i need to redirect to some other jsp page with the created return value from the spring controller which is json value.

Comment: Dont post image or link  bro share the coding explain bit more.

Comment: added code and explanation bro..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer to this question. But please confirm whether it is right.

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(emp.getId()).toUri());